# Customer CSS Pre-Loader

Tags: css, preloader

So, I have this CSS pre-loader working.  However, I'm having some difficulty adding this to my site.  Could someone help me to understand the implementation of the code to allow for the pre-loader to be the first item viewed until the site is loaded.  At which point the pre-loader will fade out.  The code for the the pre-loader is as follows :

```
 <div class = "container">
    <div id="css-preloader">

    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>

    </div>
    </div>
```

/* CSS */

```
#.container {
  width: 100%;
}
#css-preloader{
  position:relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10% 0 0 45%;
}
#css-preloader span{
  display: block;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #e43632;
  position: absolute;
  animation: preloader_1 2.25s  infinite ease-in-out;
}

#css-preloader span:nth-child(2){
  left: 11px;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(3){
  left:22px;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(4){
  left:33px;
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(5){
  left:44px;
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(6){
  left: 55px;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(7){
  left: 66px;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
#css-preloader span:nth-child(8){
  left: 77px;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
### #css-preloader span:nth-child(9){
  left: 88px;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
@keyframes preloader_1 {
###0% {
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  background: #fdcf01;
 }

25% {
  height: 60px;
  transform: translateY(15px);
  background: #4bb846;
}
50% {
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
  background:#2988dd;
}  
100% {
  height: 10px;
  transform: translateY(0px);
  background: #e43632;
  }
}
```

Comment: You did not have to separate class and id. You list id first, then class, in the same div tag. The DOM will isolate the definitions. This is not a fix, just a clean-up suggestion. If your using 2 div's for separate functions, you need some html code so you have objects to work with.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Please do not us IDs for the styling purposes** https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-IDs-in-selectors
2. Do not name your CSS classes **.css-preloader** try to be more general. Something that is defined in CSS must be CSS so no need for the prefix.
3. Good pointers **@osmanraifgunes** but we are living in 2016 so no need jQuery for this simple task. Simple usage of window.onload combined with document.querySelector will do the trick. Also $(document).ready is fired once DOM is fully loaded not all the resources on the page. For that we need to use window.onload in plain JS or $(window).load in jQuery...
4. Instead of using jQuery hide(), you can just add CSS class **.hidden** to the preloader once the content is fully loaded... This approach provides you with a possibilities of using CSS3 animations.

I modified your code a bit and added the JS logic, here is the demo:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  addCls('.preloader', 'hidden');
}

function addCls(selector, cls) {
  var element = document.querySelector(selector);
  element.classList.add(cls);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
}
.holder {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 93px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: -5px 0px 0px -46px;
}
.preloader {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: all 1.5s ease;
}
.preloader.hidden {
  top: -150%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.preloader span {
  display: block;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  background: #e43632;
  position: absolute;
  animation: preloader-animation 2.25s infinite ease-in-out;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(2) {
  left: 11px;
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(3) {
  left: 22px;
  animation-delay: .4s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(4) {
  left: 33px;
  animation-delay: .6s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(5) {
  left: 44px;
  animation-delay: .8s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(6) {
  left: 55px;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(7) {
  left: 66px;
  animation-delay: 1.2s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(8) {
  left: 77px;
  animation-delay: 1.4s;
}
.preloader span:nth-child(9) {
  left: 88px;
  animation-delay: 1.6s;
}
@keyframes preloader-animation {
  0% {
    height: 10px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: #fdcf01;
  }
  25% {
    height: 60px;
    transform: translateY(15px);
    background: #4bb846;
  }
  50% {
    height: 10px;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    background: #2988dd;
  }
  100% {
    height: 10px;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    background: #e43632;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/64609/pexels-photo-64609.jpeg" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/8139/pexels-photo.jpg" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/10979/pexels-photo-10979.jpeg" />
  <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/24326/pexels-photo-24326.jpg" />
  <div class="preloader">
    <div class="holder">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with using an ID to style an element if that styling is needed for one unique element. That's what IDs are for.

Comment: I can see your point and can agree to some extent. It can be personal choice to take one approach or another. Main reason why I do not like ids in CSS is reusability, which is part of OOP and DRY mindset. Code from above needs to be refactored so that it can fully support styling without ids. By refactoring I mean changing .preloader to .overlay.full and .holder to .loader, something like that... Overlay wrapper which takes full viewport / parent element space sure can be reused, same goes to loader.

Comment: Using IDs is preferable in most cases. That also makes teamwork easier. Imagine simple situation. We work together and your job is to create some HTML block inside the element `#menu` and I work with `#footer` on the same page. Using IDs in CSS allow us both to write a class with a same name and be sure that they don't interfere, such as `#menu .node {...}` written by you and `#footer .node {...}` written by me. That way we don't need to know all class-names other people use. If you put CSS just like `.node {...}`, we're all in trouble ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set `z-index` of your loader 99 (should be biggest z-indexed element inside page).

```
z-index:99;
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.classOfTheLoader').hide();
});
```

Note that jquery is needed.